# GWT ,Vaadin,SmartGwt,ExtGwt ?---from Swing

Tags: java, swing, gwt

I start to migrate an old Swing app to web interface:

Alternatives I want : 
       Gwt, Vaadin,Smart Gwt, Ext Gwt

The profile of the app is a custom ERP.

Big question is which ?

Why GWT do not have rich components like Vaadin ,SmartGwt and ExtGwt has ?

DO you know any GWT component library ?

Thanks.

Comment: I do that ...very hard ..very hard to choose!

Comment: The problem with choosing the BEST answer as the RIGHT answer is that it would discourage further answers to the question. Cris comes here to have his/her question answered, not to play the politics of increasing forum points. The BEST answer is not always the RiGHT answer.

Comment: I read a lot of blogs,pro ,cons for each of them...just did not decided yet...maybe some opinions here will open my eyes better in order to choose

Comment: Closed as not productive in 3.. 2.. 1..

Comment: Search the Vaadin and ExtGWT forums for "smartgwt" and you will find a number of people requesting features that exist in SmartGWT, or trying to add a SmartGWT widget to a Vaadin or ExtGWT app to get those features.. there's no corresponding requests on SmartGWT forums.  So, SmartGWT is my product, but I submit that this is clear, verifiable evidence that SmartGWT is the most feature rich, which matters a lot for a complex application like ERP.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't think there is a definite answer for this one. I started about 2 years ago with all this web-dev maze and I have theses conclusions:

- GWT: This framework is really all about abstracting you from the "real" web development. The framework has evolved a lot since I use it. It has gotten better and they are continually introducing interesting new concepts and options for you to build your app. They leave a hole lot of freedom to the dev. This can be a good thing since it can be nice to choose components you already know. Say you know JQuery, they have GQuery, you know Hibernate you can use it, Spring you can use it. But, to much freedom is kind of daunting for GWT beginners since it's hard to plug all the components to get an enterprise application. Is it that hard? Not really you get used to it's concepts and start liking it. As far as Widget goes, they do not offer as many eye candy stuff as Vaadin, gxt or Smart but I like to stick with the bases.
- Smart: I used SmartGWT for enterprise level projets and it does the job. It has many great components that will get you where you want. It is a huge framework though and it gets complex when something doesn't work as you expected. But, you could be happy with it. It gets a bit hard to use layouts sometimes.
- GXT: Really nice. They offer a lot of great widgets, yes. They offer good support, yes. You have to pay :( yes. Unless you are an Open source project, you will have to pay fees to use it. The baseline is, I abandoned it until they release the version 3.0. Why? They are syncing with GWT roadmap. They will be using the same event handling and UI binders. I'm waiting for this to ease my dev. time. Sometimes you also want to mix (which might not be the greatest idea) but the event model being different from the GWT one is pretty crappy.

Bottom line, I sticking with GWT for now. They will continue enhancing it and the support community is great! But you won't get a savvy UI which you could get with any of the frameworks.

good luck

Comment: Thanks...that is the conclusion for now ...stick with GWT. Saw some very nice sites done with plain GWT.

Comment: I'm planing to keep a long term app with GWT so I don't want to add some other dependency to my stack. GXT is quite good but I strongly believe GWT will payback in the long run.

Comment: the only drawback is the lack of ready to use widgets...:(.

Comment: GWT's widgets are evolving very slowly and the GWT team has marked many component enhancements as "contributions welcome".  They are meanwhile doing great work on GWT core things like SuperDevMode.  So I wouldn't bet on GWT core widgets ever catching SmartGWT, GXT or even Vaadin, but then SmartGWT is my product.